# 400 BadRequest при передаче данных в @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring-boot, url, tomcat, path

Есть контроллер:

```java
    @RequestMapping(path = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(@RequestParam String str ) throws IOException {
            File file2Upload = new File(str);
            Path path = Paths.get(file2Upload.getAbsolutePath());
            ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(path));
    
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                    .body(resource);
        }
```

Когда я ввожу путь к файлу `C:\Users\Илья\Pictures\Screenshots\SRE.png` я получаю этот файл, но когда я устанавливаю аннотацию `@PathVariable`:

```java
     @RequestMapping(path = "/download/{str}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(@PathVariable String str ) throws IOException {
```

Получаю ответ `HTTP 400`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `@PathVariable` нельзя передавать `/`, так как `TomCat` ограничивает использование некоторых символов в целях безопасности и построения url. Вы можете использовать `@RequestParam`. Более подробно вы можете ознакомиться [здесь](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-7.3).

Comment: Столько времени потратил. Большое Спасибо!